# C++ Loops, trying to increase one value by using another value you input

Tags: c++

First of this is a homework assignment, I want to be up front and honest with that. Second of all I'm sorry for the messy and bad code, I'm taking an intro to C++ class. Third I've been having issues with using loops and I can't seem to figure out how to increase the value of rent by the amount of rentI in my program. I've tried using the addition operator but it only increases the value once.

```
#include<cmath>
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rent;
    int office;
    int rentI;
    int maint;

    cout << "Enter number of offices: ";
    cin >> office;
    cout << "Enter the rent for each occupied unit: ";
    cin >> rent;
    cout << "Enter the desired number to increase rent by for each vacant unit: ";
    cin >> rentI;
    cout << "Enter the cost of each rented units maintenance: ";
    cin >> maint;

    int profit = (rent * office) - (office * maint);
    cout << "unit #  |" << "rent |" << "profit" << endl;
    //cout << setw(5) << office << setw(8) << rent << setw(8) << profit << endl;
    
    int i = 0;
    //while (i < 5)
    //{
        //cout << setw(5) << office-- << setw(8) << rent << setw(8) << profit << "\n";
        //i++;
    //}

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << office--;
        cout << setw(8) << rent;
        cout << setw(8) << profit << "\n";
    }
}
```

also I was experimenting with while loops but that didn't seem to help either. I know I could be missing something I just don't know what it is.

```
unit #  |rent |profit
   50     600   28650
   49     600   28650
   48     600   28650
   47     600   28650
   46     600   28650
```

this is what it does now, but I need it to do something like this.

```
unit #  |rent |profit
   50     600   28650
   49     640   30037
   48     680   31344
   47     720   32571
   46     760   33718
```

Comment: Are you looking for `rent += rentI;` ?

Comment: `int i = 0;` followed by just comments, and then `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {`. And That loop never modifies `i`, so it'll loop forever

Comment: I've tried using rent += rentI before never seem to work, the whole int i = 0; was for the while loop that's above the for loop, I was just testing to see if I could get a while loop to work, sadly I did not. When putting the formula into the loop I can only get it to increase once then not do it again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `profit` calculation inside the loop, and update `office` and `rent` after doing the calculation.

```
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++, office--, rent += rentI)
    {
        int profit = (rent * office) - (office * maint);
        cout << setw(5) << office;
        cout << setw(8) << rent;
        cout << setw(8) << profit << "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! that makes way more sense.